# One firebase database for every customer

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms

I have one mobile app, and every customer have a lot of data under user account. It is possible to make one database firebase for each customer ? Xamarin app...

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create multiple databases directly from the Firebase Console as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding#create_multiple_instances).

In case you need to create the databases programmatically as new users sign up or so, then you need to use [Firebase Realtime Database Management API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/database-management/rest).

To create a new database, make a POST request:

```
https://firebasedatabase.googleapis.com/v1beta/{parent=projects/*/locations/*}/instances
```